# Same scale for the axes in Graphics (2D)

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm trying to establish the same scales for two axes while using Graphics. I don't know the potential size ('plotrange') of the picture, so AspectRatio doesn't help. ScalingFunctions can't be applied to Graphics. Is there any equivalent of this?

Comment: Can you provide some sample code that illustrates what you are trying to accomplish? Have you looked at [Scale](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scale.html)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this? Same axes scales for originally rectangular image.

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Apples"}];
Graphics[{Yellow, Rectangle[{0, 0}, {400, 400}],
  Inset[ImageResize[image, {400, 400}], {0, 0}, {0, 0}, 400]},
 PlotRange -> {{0, 400}, {0, 400}}, ImageSize -> 400,
 Frame -> True]
```

[image]